# Fade In / Fade out 2 Labels infinite loop inside tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to show an intermittent label with two changing strings (like a banner) in an infinite loop.
The first label should fade in. After that it should fade out and let a second label do the same. Then repeat the sequence infinitely or a long time.
The label is inside a subclass of a UITableView.

I tried this so far:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  ...
  // Inside a cell an at its own section of the tableview
  cell.label1.alpha = 1;

            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

            [UIView setAnimationDuration:3];
            [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
            [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:INFINITY];
            [cell.label1 setAlpha:0];
            [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];

            [UIView commitAnimations];

            cell.label2.alpha = 1;

            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

            [UIView setAnimationDuration:3];
            [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
            [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:INFINITY];
            [cell.label1 setAlpha:0];
            [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];

            [UIView commitAnimations];

...
}
```

This code works fine but the effect is not clear because the fade in label1 is crossing fade out label2 and it is weird.
So, how can I make a break between the two animations, to see the fading labels clearly?

Comment: Use keyframe animation http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/04/01/stop-nesting-animation-blocks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Paulw11 for your answer, now it works fine, here is my code with the changes:

```
cell.label2.alpha = 0;
            cell.label1.alpha = 1;

            [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:15 delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
                [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.25 animations:^{
                    cell.label1.alpha = 0;
                    cell.label2.alpha = 0;
                    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                }];
                [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.25 relativeDuration:0.25 animations:^{
                    cell.label1.alpha = 0;
                    cell.label2.alpha = 1;
                    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                }];
                [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.50 relativeDuration:0.25 animations:^{
                    cell.label1.alpha = 0;
                    cell.label2.alpha = 0;
                    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                }];
                [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.75 relativeDuration:0.25 animations:^{
                    cell.label1.alpha = 1;
                    cell.label2.alpha = 0;
                    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                }];

                [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount: 200];


            } completion:nil];
```